# git-commit-mode with flyspell very slow

Tags: magit, git, flyspell

I use emacsclient as my git commit editor.

This is what I have in my init file:

```
(require 'git-commit)
(add-hook 'git-commit-mode-hook 'turn-on-flyspell)
```

I just made a huge commit (update of a third-party SDK, which I have in my own repo). Emacsclient took absurdly much time spell checking what looks to be all the source files, instead of the commit message only. Like 15 minutes.

The default commit message shows the name of all changed files.

- is `flyspell` trying to spell check everything because the filenames are in the default commit message?
- is `magit` the problem, trying to display diff? In that case, how can I setup my hook so that the commit message is spell checked, but not the source diff? I don't *think* I have spell check activated when I run magit normally.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that flyspell indeed checks the text in the comments (*), which is why `git-commit.el` provides an alternative to `turn-on-flyspell` that doesn't have that issue.

```
(add-hook 'git-commit-setup-hook 'git-commit-turn-on-flyspell)
```

Also note that this uses a hook different from the one you were using.

(*) Well kind of, see https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/24c966082bdfb16552c7f35bcd38426a321c4b89.

Comment: I've tried with `git-commit-turn-on-flyspell`, both with the hook you suggested and the one I used to use. Still checking an awful lot. I have to `kill` emacs (`kill -9`, even).

Comment: With no hook at all (well, I'm not sure if `magit` doesn't add something there), the text shows up fine, but the buffer is very slow to navigate. The size of the COMMIT_EDITMSG is roughly 7000 rows.

Comment: The minor modes I have left are `Async-Bytecomp-Package Auto-Composition Auto-Compression
Auto-Encryption Auto-Fill Blink-Cursor Dtrt-Indent Dumb-Jump Electric-Indent
File-Name-Shadow Flx-Ido Font-Lock Git-Commit Global-Cwarn Global-Font-Lock
Global-Git-Commit Ido-Everywhere Line-Number Mouse-Wheel Shell-Dirtrack
Show-Paren Tooltip With-Editor Ws-Trim`. But maybe that'd be for another question.

Comment: There isn't much anyone else can do for you at this point. You will have to figure out yourself what part of your setup triggers the issue. A good way to accomplish this is to do a binary search on your configuration by commenting out parts of it, and then other parts, or only a subset, until you have found the cause.